# Vector out of range (Batch rendering & opengl)

Tags: opengl, c++, vector

So ive (tried to) implement a batch rendering system, and at the for loop the error pops up and I'm not shure what ive done wrong. Any suggestions to improve the system would be much appreciated. (It's my first time trying to implement this)

```
#include "masterRenderer.h"

masterRenderer::masterRenderer() {
    quad = vector<Quad>(1000);
    numOf = 0;
} 

void masterRenderer::addQuad(Quad quad) {
    masterRenderer::quad[numOf] = quad;
    numOf++;
}

void masterRenderer::init(GLuint shader, string texPath) {
    vector<GLfloat> vertex((3 * 4) * (numOf + 1));
    vector<GLfloat> normals((3 * 4) * (numOf + 1));
    vector<GLfloat> color((3 * 4) * (numOf + 1));
    vector<GLfloat> uv((2 * 4) * (numOf + 1));

    int nv = 0, nn = 0, nc = 0, nu = 0;

    GLfloat sizeV = 0, sizeN = 0, sizeC = 0, sizeUv = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numOf; i++) {      // The error seems to pop up over here.
        for (int j = 0; j < 3 * 4; j++) {
            vertex[nv] = quad[i].g_vertex_buffer_data[j];
            sizeV += quad[i].g_vertex_buffer_data[j];
            nv++;
            normals[nn] = quad[i].g_normal_buffer_bata[j];
            sizeN += quad[i].g_normal_buffer_bata[j];
            nn++;
            color[nc] = quad[i].g_color_buffer_data[j];
            sizeC += quad[i].g_color_buffer_data[j];
            nc++;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * 4; j++) {
            uv[nc] = quad[i].g_uv_buffer_data[j];
            sizeUv += quad[i].g_uv_buffer_data[j];
            nc++;
        }
    }

    TextureID = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "textureSampler");
    texture_handle = Util::loadTexture("test.png");

    glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(sizeN), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(sizeC), &color[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(sizeUv), &uv[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(sizeV), &vertex[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void masterRenderer::draw(glm::mat4 Model, glm::mat4 View, glm::mat4 Projection, GLuint MatrixID) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_handle);
    glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    for (int i = 0; i < numOf + 1; i++) {
        Model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(quad[i - 1].pos.x, quad[i - 1].pos.y, quad[i - 1].pos.z));
        Model = glm::rotate(Model, glm::radians(quad[i-1].yrot), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

        glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 4 * i - 1, 4 * i);
    }
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glPopMatrix();
}

masterRenderer::~masterRenderer() { }
```

Comment: where and how do you call `masterRenderer::AddQuad()`? Is it before calling init or after?

Comment: Add quad after the quads are initialized then init.

Comment: probably not related, but what for do you do sums like `sizeV += quad[i].g_vertex_buffer_data[j];`? Also, is `sizeV` ever used?

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in lines copying data to buffers, you give it incorrect size - not taking in account actual size of data. The second parameter should be size of data in bytes, the `sizeof(sizeN)` will **always** return 4 (=the size of `GLfloat`). For example, instead of

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(sizeN), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

you probably meant

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * sizeN, &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

the size of *one* `GLfloat` times number of `GLfloat`s. Moreover, there is no need to keep incrementing the `sizeN`(also it should not be floating point type if you count integer number of elements) because you can get the element count directly from vector:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * normals.size(), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

same applies to all buffers.
For the out of range problem I suggest you use `push_back()` and `reserve()` instead, this should avoid any of these problems completely. Summing it up:

```
void masterRenderer::init(GLuint shader, string texPath) {
vector<GLfloat> vertex;
vector<GLfloat> normals;
vector<GLfloat> color;
vector<GLfloat> uv;

vertex.reserve((3 * 4) * (numOf + 1));
normals.reserve((3 * 4) * (numOf + 1));
color.reserve((3 * 4) * (numOf + 1));
uv.reserve((2 * 4) * (numOf + 1));

for (int i = 0; i < numOf; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < 3 * 4; j++) {
        vertex.push_back(quad[i].g_vertex_buffer_data[j]);
        normals.push_back(quad[i].g_normal_buffer_bata[j]);
        color.push_back(quad[i].g_color_buffer_data[j]);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 2 * 4; j++)
        uv.push_back(quad[i].g_uv_buffer_data[j]);
}

TextureID = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "textureSampler");
texture_handle = Util::loadTexture("test.png");

glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * normals.size(), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * color.size(), &color[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * uv.size(), &uv[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertex.size(), &vertex[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Comment: ...I am not sure if this is the only error in you code but hope it helps, be sure to comment/expand your question.